# How to make private user repos with Site admin access through Github API

Tags: github-api, egit

This is API call ....repos/user/repo ....
its working fine when I connect GitHub through user credentials....

but when I try to login with site admin credentials..... it’s throwing 404 error Code.

This indicates that user can only modify his own repos....other users even site admin or org owner can’t update user repos. 
Is it true??

Can someone please confirm or provide if any alternate solution.

This is API call ....repos/user/repo ....
its working fine when I connect GitHub through user credentials....

but when I try to login with site admin credentials..... it’s throwing 404 error Code.

This indicates that user can only modify his own repos....other users even site admin or org owner can’t update user repos. 
Is it true??

Can someone please confirm or provide if any alternate solution.

Thanks,
Krishna